# Why is my attempt to add an A record to Route53 using the AWS CLI failing?

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-route53

I expect I'm missing something dumb here.  Can anyone see what I'm missing?

I have a file named `/tmp/r53.json` that contains the following:

```json
{
    "Changes": [{
    "Action": "UPSERT",
        "ResourceRecordSet": {
            "Name": "squidproxy.idev.in.",
            "Type": "A",
            "TTL": 300,
            "ResourceRecords": [ {"Value": "10.10.3.119"} ]
        }
    }]
}
```

And I am running the command:

```
aws route53 change-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id Z30M8MWTQXQ2O2 --change-batch file:///tmp/r53.json
```

which give me the error:

```
An error occurred (InvalidChangeBatch) when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: [RRSet with DNS name squidproxy.idev.in. is not permitted in zone iddev.in.]
```

I know that I have specified the zone correctly because I see the zone name `iddev.in` in the error message, and I'm not specifying that name anywhere.

Why is this command failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your domain name `squidproxy.idev.in` is not a subdomain of `iddev.in`. Your root domain has two `d` characters in it (`iddev`) while the record you are trying to create has one `d` character in it (`idev`).

Comment: DOH!  I knew I just needed another set of eyes.  Funny how you can stare and stare at something and miss a thing like that.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I've been there. Glad I could help.